# jQuery Find all a elements that starts with m and find next increased value of m?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="name">
    <a id="m2">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 2 *****</a>
</div>
<div class="name">
    <a id="m7">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 7 *****</a>
</div>
<div class="name">
    <a id="m1">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 1 *****</a>
</div>
<div class="name">
    <a id="m3">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 3 *****</a>
</div>
```

So i need to get all a tags that starts with m and find next number that does not exists..in my example i have:

```
m2
m7
m1
m3
```

So the next number that does not exists is m4 then calling again function i will get m5 and then m6 and then m8 and so on.

I read all a tag values that starts with m using this jQuery code:

```
var m = [];
$("a[id^=m]").each(function(){ m.push(this.id); });
```

So i think i need to get next in order value that does not exists in array or can be done more simple using simple function that do it for me in simplier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for` loop and use `includes` to check the element exist from ana array.

```js
var m = [];
$("a[id^=m]").each(function() {m.push(this.id);});

var maxNum = 10;                                     //Max number to check
var missing = [];                                    //Init missing array variable
for (i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++) {                      //Loop from 1 to max number
  if (!m.includes('m' + i)) missing.push('m' + i);   //Check if exist in m array, if not, push to missing array
}

console.log(missing);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name">
  <a id="m2">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 2 *****</a>
</div>
<div class="name">
  <a id="m7">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 7 *****</a>
</div>
<div class="name">
  <a id="m1">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 1 *****</a>
</div>
<div class="name">
  <a id="m3">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 3 *****</a>
</div>
```

---

Option 2:

```js
var maxNum = 10;
var missing = [];
var exist = [];
for (i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++) {
  if ($('#m' + i).length) exist.push('m' + i);
  else missing.push('m' + i);
}

console.log('missing', missing);
console.log('exist', exist);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name">
  <a id="m2">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 2 *****</a>
</div>
<div class="name">
  <a id="m7">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 7 *****</a>
</div>
<div class="name">
  <a id="m1">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 1 *****</a>
</div>
<div class="name">
  <a id="m3">&nbsp;&nbsp;***** HOUSE 3 *****</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works great...but i would like to use each or map function from jquery because i think it will execute more fastwer that looping and finding missing number...

Answer (score 1):

Loop over to generate id of an element dynamically

```
    var foundElement = [];
    var notFoundElement = [];
    var limit = 100; //define finite limit otherwise browser may go mad
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i< limit; i++){
        var elementId = '#m' + i;
        if($(elementId).length > 0){
            console.log('Element with id: m' + i + ' found.');
            foundElement.push(elementId);
        }else{
            console.log('Element with id: m' + i + ' not found.');
            notFoundElement.push(elementId);
        }
    }
    console.log('Array of found elements: ' + foundElement);
    console.log('Array of not found elements: ' + notFoundElement);
```